# Android Bluetooth Gatt getValue returns an 20-sized array of 0 bytes

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

My android application communicates via ble to an RN4871 ble chip. I have previously made it work with a chip that has been upgraded to firmware version 1.3.

My issue is when the firmware is version 1.18, which I need to support. When sending certain messages, onCharacteristicChange's getValue method continuously returns a 20-size array of 0 bytes, about 10 times a second.

I have sent the same packet via the same phone's Serial Bluetooth application and the reply works as expected.

I have tried using getStringValue, the result is 20 null (ASCII 0) characters

```java
       @Override
       public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }

        private void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            byte[] messageBytes = characteristic.getValue();
            String message = StringUtils.stringFromBytes(messageBytes);
            Log.d("Status", message);
        }
```

The expected message to be print should be a string, but what was printed is 20-nullchar (��������������������������������������)

Comment: If onCharacteristicChanged() is called several times, it means the characteristic's value is written several times. Does your app call writeCharacteristic() and what value is written ?

Comment: No, my app does not call the writeCharacteristic. Its the embbed device (BLE chip) that calls it when it sends message to the Android application

Comment: It means it's the firmware of your BLE device that writes the characteristic several times with arrays of null bytes